# How to create NodeJS server using http-server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpserver

I am new to Nodejs and would like to know how to use http server using the modejs http-server module.

I did the following steps:
1. Installed Nodejs.
2. Installed http-server module using the command : npm install http-server -g
3. Created a folder with a HTML doc

Once I start the server using the command http-server, the URL provides the following output:

192.168.1.5 sent an invalid response

CMD commmand :

```
C:\Users\user\folderLocation>http-server
```

HTML output :

```
192.168.1.5 sent an invalid response
```

Pls. do help with with this issue and provide feedback with what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

```
http-server -p8080 . //serves current directory
http-server -p8080 ./public //serves directory named public
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: what is your folder structure

Comment: Desktop->Folder1->folder2->(css,js,index.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently there is a bug](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/525) in a dependency of the recent version of `http-server`. [One solution](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/525#issuecomment-493210930) is to install `http-server@0.9.0`